# Tailwind CSS custom shadow is not working

Tags: reactjs, shadow, tailwind-css

Tailwind CSS custom shadow is not working in my app.

I am trying to apply Tailwind CSS custom shadow on div, which is inside my Card component, but I don't not why it is not working. Although, Tailwind CSS official document states the same as I applied.

Here is my code

```js
const Card = (props) => { return(  <div className={${props.className} relative inline-flex items-center gap-4 py-2 px-4 w-fit box-shadow rounded-xl m-2 shadow-[0px_16px_11px_rgba(0, 0, 0,0.3)]}> {props. children} </div> );
};
export default Card;
```

Comment: Should make an [edit] to include your code.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because you are missing backticks around your classname?

something like this:

```
const Card = (props) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={`${props.className} relative inline-flex items-center gap-4 py-2 px-4 w-fit box-shadow rounded-xl m-2 shadow-[0px_16px_11px_rgba(0, 0, 0,0.3)]`}
    >
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}
export default Card
```

Comment: Backticks are there, I removed them because stack overflow takes them as code separation.